# How to update tableview section row array value and delete particular row value using Swift?

Tags: swift

My scenario, I am using tableview with two sections. First sections having one row and another sections having five rows. Here, data  I am loading from array. I need to update and replace the value in array also need to show and hide particular row in a section.

```
var settings_sections = ["Account", "General Settings"]
var settings_title = [[“User Account"], ["Contact Us", "Share App", "Terms","Privacy", "Logout"]]
let settings_icon = [[UIImage(named: "account.png")], [UIImage(named: "contactus.png"), UIImage(named: "share.png"), UIImage(named: "terms.png"), UIImage(named: "privacy.png”), UIImage(named: "logout.png")]]
```

Here, Account section I need to update User Account initial value to my name and need to show and hide Logout row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the array elements and call [reloadData()][1]

```
var settings_title = [[“User Account"], ["Contact Us", "Share App", "Terms","Privacy", "Logout"]]

settings_title[0][0] = "Your name"
tableView.reloadData()
```

And don't use underscores in a variable declaration

Use `settingsTitle` instead of `settings_title`

```
//Hide logout
if var general = settings_title.last {
    if let logoutIndex = general.firstIndex(of: "Logout") {
        general.remove(at: logoutIndex)
    }
    settings_title[1] = general
}
tableView.reloadData()
//show logout
if var general = settings_title.last {
    general.append("Logout")
    settings_title[1] = general
}
tableView.reloadData()
```

---

Use an `array` of struct instead of creating multiple arrays.

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {
    struct Menu {
        var title: String
        var icon: UIImage?
    }
    struct Section {
        var sectionTitle: String
        var menus: [Menu]
    }
    var settingsSections = [Section(sectionTitle: "Account", menus: [Menu(title: "User Account", icon: UIImage(named: "account"))]),
                            Section(sectionTitle: "General Settings", menus:
                                [Menu(title: "Contact Us", icon: UIImage(named: "contactus")), Menu(title: "Share App", icon: UIImage(named: "share")),
                                 Menu(title: "Terms", icon: UIImage(named: "terms")), Menu(title: "Privacy", icon: UIImage(named: "privacy")),
                                 Menu(title: "Logout", icon: UIImage(named: "logout"))])]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
            self.changeName()
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10.0) {
            self.hideLogout()
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 20.0) {
            self.showLogout()
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 20.0) {
            self.showLogout()
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 20.0) {
            self.showLogout()
        }
    }
    func changeName() {
        if let account = settingsSections.first, let userAccount = account.menus.first {
            var newUser = userAccount
            newUser.title = "Your name"
            settingsSections[0].menus[0] = newUser
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    func hideLogout() {
        if let general = settingsSections.last {
            let newMenus = general.menus.filter { $0.title != "Logout" }
            settingsSections[1].menus = newMenus
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    func showLogout() {
        if let general = settingsSections.last, !general.menus.contains(where: { $0.title == "Logout" }) {
            var newMenus = general.menus
            newMenus.append(Menu(title: "Logout", icon: UIImage(named: "logout")))
            settingsSections[1].menus = newMenus
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return settingsSections.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return settingsSections[section].sectionTitle
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return settingsSections[section].menus.count
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") ?? UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        let menu = settingsSections[indexPath.section].menus[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = menu.title
        cell.imageView?.image = menu.icon
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. How to show and hide logout index @RajeshKumar

Comment: getting Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type 'String' Error @RajeshKumar

Comment: Logout not showing again. I need to reload tableview or someother mistake happened?

Comment: @jackios Yes. you need to reload tableview after making any change to the array

Comment: Icons crashing out of range index because I loaded separate array icons. so how to show and hide it. @RajeshKumar

Comment: @jackios yes. don't create separate arrays for title and image. Create an array of struct. Check updated answer

Comment: can you please update title and logout update code above you answered already. I changed struct method but getting variable error on it. @Rajeshkumar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193379/discussion-between-rajeshkumar-r-and-jackios).

Comment: @jackios Already I've updated the answer with //Change name
//Remove logout
//add logout

Comment: Logout values adding whenever reloading tableview. Its adding many times.